# Solution gets deployed to sharepoint but feature not shown in site

Tags: features

My sharepoint solution gets deployed but the feature is not shown in site collection features. How can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, verify that your feature is part of the package. You can have a package with 0 features even if the feature exists in Visual Studio.

Comment: Moreover, the scope of feature should be `Site`, if it needs to be shown in Site Collection features list.